# Manually triggering a job not working

Tags: c#, quartz.net, .net-standard-2.0, quartz.net-3.0

Using Quartz.Net I want to manually trigger a job without a schedule (for now). However the job runs on startup (which I don't want), then fails to respond to a manual trigger (main problem).

```
private IScheduler _scheduler;

public void SetupAndTestScheduler()
{
    ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
    _scheduler = sf.GetScheduler().Result;
    _scheduler.Start();
    _scheduler.ScheduleJob(
        new JobDetailImpl(nameof(TestDataJob), typeof(TestDataJob)), null);

    // manually trigger the job
    _scheduler.TriggerJob(jobKey: new JobKey(nameof(TestDataJob)));
}

public class TestDataJob : IJob
{
    public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        // blah blah blah
    }
}
```

I'm on NetStandard2.0, with Quartz.Net Alpha 3. I'm wondering whether this is a problem with version 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Quartz.Net 3.x Alpha, methods like `scheduler.Start`, `scheduler.ScheduleJob`, etc..., are now `async`, which means you need to `await` them. What happens in your code is that the `Task` returned by `ScheduleJob` is not even executed before the call to `Shutdown`, as you are not awaiting it.

You can follow the [Quick Start Guide](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/quick-start.html) to see exactly how to use it.

In a nutshell, what you need to do:

- use the `async`/`await` semantics
- add the job to the scheduler by calling the `scheduler.AddJob` method (your job must be declared as durable in that case, as you are not associating a trigger with it)
- and then you can call the `scheduler.TriggerJob()` method to trigger your job